# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-9

We are trying to migrate from Jboss 4.2.3 GA to Wildfly 8.2.1 Final. The code which was working fine in the Jboss is not working in Widfly anymore and giving the following strange exception. I have tried searching for the solution for this issue but I couldn't find any details on the exception. What could be the issue?

```
2018-05-11 12:54:38,215 ERROR [xxx.yyyy.cccccccccc] (default task-36) PersistenceProvider: default task-36: insertBlob: exception saving blob: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.PoolBySubject

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1077) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_101]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at org.apache.jsp.app.ca12.index_jsp._jspx_meth_skin_005fupdate_005f0(index_jsp.java:639)

at org.apache.jsp.app.ca12.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:128)

at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]

at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:366) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]

at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]

at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259) [jastow-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:82) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:250) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:193) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:160) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88) [csrfguard-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at com.netegrity.webapp.page.jsf.FacesFilter.doFilter2(FacesFilter.java:186) [user_console.jar:14.1.0.361]

at com.netegrity.webapp.page.jsf.FacesFilter.doFilter(FacesFilter.java:157) [user_console.jar:14.1.0.361]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147) [tomahawk-1.1.5.jar:]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at com.netegrity.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:48) [user_console.jar:14.1.0.361]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at com.netegrity.webapp.authentication.FrameworkLoginFilter.doFilter(FrameworkLoginFilter.java:319) [user_console.jar:14.1.0.361]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
```

Comment: At a wild guess you are attempting to serialize JDBC `Connection` objects, a concept which makes about as much sense as trying to fax a fax machine.

Comment: Looks like yes, But this is a very legacy code where it is working in the Jboss 4.2.3 GA version but giving problem only in the wildfly. Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue or its some bug in the wildfly?

Comment: Err, don't try to serialize JDBC `Connection` objects?

Comment: These mid-era versions of JBoss actually supported remote JNDI lookups of DataSource objects. I believe that it was resisted for a while but there was significant demand for it apparently. Unfortunately for the OP this was a non-portable extension and no longer works.